# How to fix file .json not found

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying here to consume the data from a JSON file:

**DATA.json**

```
[

{"Label"
        
        :"USA",
        "Adress":"This is the us",
        "Lat":"36.9628066",
        "Lng":"-122.0194722"
},
{ "Label"  :"USA",
         "Address":"2020",
          "Lat":"36.9628066", 
          "Lng":"-122.0194722" }

]
```

**Then applying it in my `Mainclass`:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;


namespace Orbage
{
    

class MapPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MapPage()
        {
            CustomMap customMap = new CustomMap
            {
                MapType = MapType.Street

            };
            // ...
            Content = customMap;

            var json = File.ReadAllText("File.json");
            var places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<File>>(json);
            foreach (var place in places)
            {
                CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
                {
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(Double.Parse(place.Lat), Double.Parse(place.Lng)),
                    Label = place.Label,
                    Address = place.Address,
                    Name = "Xamarin",

                    Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
                };



                customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };

                customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
                customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37.79752, -122.40183), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
            }
        }
    }


}
```

But when I put the file in there it says that it doesn't exist.

**Error:**

> FilenotfoundException

Whats the fix for this.

I tried:

- Changing the location of the file.
- Its name
  = Instead of E:/-/- I even wrote `file.json` but I still get the same error.

Comment: Please help me!

Comment: @Jason the error is not coming now but the marker isn't showing

Comment: changing the question you asked completely invalidates the answer that I gave you.  Please don't do that.

Comment: oops sorry I din't know that..... Please retype the answer and add this line MainPage = new Orbage.MapPage(); Because that was the fix and the using forms.

Comment: where is your custom renderer?

Comment: Do you add a file and ensure that `Build Action`: `EmbeddedResource` like this thread? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows#loading-files-embedded-as-resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is how you are trying to access your json. I'm not sure(because it doesn't say) as to where are you storing it, but [here the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/#reading-or-writing-to-files-on-internal-storage) explain a smooth explanation as to how access stored files in a mobile phone using Xamarin Forms

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You want to read from 'DATA.json' but gave the path 'File.json'.

Comment: No, That was only for the answerer to understand what I wrote there.. Thanks for writing the answer!